# Use JAVA library for iOS in React Native

Tags: java, ios, react-native

As we know that Java library can be used for Android part in React Native, is there any way to use this JAVA library for iOS also.

Answer (score 1):

No. React Native on iOS requires a platform-specific implementation, written in either Objective-C or Swift.